# Display multiple summary statistics depending on user selection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app where a user can select a state `parent_location` and a county `name` from two drop downs. They can also select a variable of interest `layer` which will then produce a summary statistics table. I've got my code working up to this point.

What I need to do is select other similar counties (contained in the `cluster` column) and then display summary statistics for this county as well. I can't seem to figure out how to A) display multiple summary statistics tables and B) dynamically create a list of similar counties.

Code that works

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

eviction_county_2010 <- read.csv("./eviction_county_2010.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "year",
              label = "Select a Year:",
              min = 2010,
              max = 2016,
              value = 2010,
              step = 1),

  radioButtons(inputId = "layer",
               label = "Select a Dataset to View:",
               choices = c("Eviction Filing Rate"="eviction_filing_rate", "Percent Rent Burden"="rent_burden",
                           "Percent Renter Occupied"="pct_renter_occupied", "Poverty Rate"="poverty_rate")),

  selectInput(inputId = "state",
              label = "Select a State:",
              eviction_county_2010$parent_location),
  selectInput(inputId = "county",
              label = "Select a County:",
              choices = NULL),
  mainPanel(
    h2("Summary of the variable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("sum")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    x <- filter(eviction_county_2010,parent_location == input$state) %>%
      select(name)
    updateSelectInput(session,"county","Select a County:",choices = unique(x))}
  )

    output$sum <- renderPrint({
      ec <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
        filter(parent_location == input$state) %>%
        filter(name == input$county)
      summary(ec[,input$layer])
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Code I've attempted for displaying for similar counties. It returns `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext(): Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)` I'm not sure which part needs to be placed inside a reactive expression.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "year",
              label = "Select a Year:",
              min = 2010,
              max = 2016,
              value = 2010,
              step = 1),

  radioButtons(inputId = "layer",
               label = "Select a Dataset to View:",
               choices = c("Eviction Filing Rate"="eviction_filing_rate", "Percent Rent Burden"="rent_burden",
                           "Percent Renter Occupied"="pct_renter_occupied", "Poverty Rate"="poverty_rate")),

  selectInput(inputId = "state",
              label = "Select a State:",
              eviction_county_2010$parent_location),
  selectInput(inputId = "county",
              label = "Select a County:",
              choices = NULL),
  mainPanel(
    h2("Summary of the variable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("sum")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ec <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
    filter(parent_location == input$state) %>%
    filter(name == input$county)
  sel_clust <- unique(ec$cluster)
  sim_cty <- eviction_county_2010[ sample(which(eviction_county_2010$cluster == sel_clust), 4),]
  sim_cty <- unique(sim_cty$GEOID)
  sim_cty <- append(sim_cty, unique(ec$GEOID))

  observe({
    x <- filter(eviction_county_2010,parent_location == input$state) %>%
      select(name)
    updateSelectInput(session,"county","Select a County:",choices = unique(x))}
  )

    output$sum <- renderPrint({
    df1 <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
      filter(GEOID == sim_cty[1])
    df2 <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
      filter(GEOID == sim_cty[2])
    df3 <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
      filter(GEOID == sim_cty[3])
    df4 <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
      filter(GEOID == sim_cty[4])
    df5 <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
      filter(GEOID == sim_cty[5])
    summary(df1[,input$layer])
    summary(df2[,input$layer])
    summary(df3[,input$layer])
    summary(df4[,input$layer])
    summary(df5[,input$layer])
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is this even possible? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this section:

```
ec <- eviction_county_2010 %>%
    filter(parent_location == input$state) %>%
    filter(name == input$county)
  sel_clust <- unique(ec$cluster)
  sim_cty <- eviction_county_2010[ sample(which(eviction_county_2010$cluster == sel_clust), 4),]
  sim_cty <- unique(sim_cty$GEOID)
  sim_cty <- append(sim_cty, unique(ec$GEOID))
```

To a reactive({}) statement. I think that's where your error is.

For example:

```
ec <- reactive({
eviction_county_2010 %>%
    filter(parent_location == input$state) %>%
    filter(name == input$county)
  sel_clust <- unique(ec$cluster)
  sim_cty <- eviction_county_2010[ sample(which(eviction_county_2010$cluster == sel_clust), 4),]
  sim_cty <- unique(sim_cty$GEOID)
  sim_cty <- append(sim_cty, unique(ec$GEOID))
})
```

Then later in your sever code use:

```
ec() %>%
...stuff...
```

Comment: what if I wanted to do `eviction_county_2010 %>% filter(GEOID %in% sim_cty)`? It doesn't seem to work on my end.

Comment: If you need to return multiple things from the reactive environment, you could do `list(sim_city = sim_city, sel_clst = sel_clyst)`  as the last object in your reactive environment then reference it later in your code as `ec()$sel_clst, ec()$sim_city`, etc